# Spring boot native with graalvm lambda with aws api gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I have build the spring boot native application using graalvm . Then I am able to deploy spring boot native executables in aws lambda (Custom runtime Amazon linux). Then I have add the triggers
for that lambda using aws apigateway . When I hit the Api Gateway it invokes the lambda .It's started but not forwarding the request to controller or endpoints .

I have used the integration type as lambda proxy in api gateway. With same endpoints

/getMethod as resources and http method as GET. Same used in spring boot native . But still its not working.